# Kurtosis to detect non-random signals in a spectrum

Tags: signal-processing, signal-detection

I have a spectrum that was created from a time series using the FFT.  The spectrum has several man-made "channels" in it; some of these are one-bin wide, some are several adjacent bins wide (larger bandwidth).

I am trying to find these signals.  I am considering using kurtosis to do this.  Since everything that is not part of a channel is likely Gaussian, normally distributed noise, I will simply exclude everything that fits this description.

For each frequency I create a time series to check for this 'randomness'.  My question is, does this time series need to be created specially?  Do I need to sample each frequency at a certain rate, before checking for normality?

Comment: In other words, you're looking for patterns in the signals, correct? Why limit the moments to only one, kurtosis? Rob Hyndman has a paper on global pattern analysis for clustering (pattern fitting) that leverages metrics including all moments, when they exist, titled *Dimension Reduction for Clustering Time Series Using
Global Characteristics*.  An ungated copy can be found here ... https://robjhyndman.com/papers/wang2.pdf

Comment: @DJohnson - I'm just wanting to locate where signals are in the spectrum.  I'm trying to do this by eliminating the noise floor - everything else is a signal (and there are many).

Comment: Good clarification but you still don't explain how use of a single moment from the distribution, the kurtosis, helps answer it.